# How do I sort a user input based on many different components in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on making a program that organizes and keep track of all the vinyl records I own. The idea is that the user (me) will be prompted with a series of questions (Artist name, Album, Genre, and record size). I would like to be able to go back and easily pull up all my blues records for example or to look through just my 45 size records. I am curranty trying to accomplish this using a dictionary, though I am at an impasse as I don't know how I would implement the sorting that want.
Thank you for your time, and I am sorry is this is not formatted correctly its my first time here.

Here is what I have so far :

```
#Record Library
'''
The objective of this project is to create a program that will take in
information regarding the Records in my collection and then sort them by
artist, genre, and record size (45/70/35)
'''

'''
I hope to have it save all the data to a text file that can be read as is or
gone through in the program. It should allow you to see all records by an artist,
in a certain genre, or of a specific size. I would also like to make a favorites
group. 
'''



def welcome():
    print("Welcome to the Vinyl Record Library")
    print("A tool to keep track of all your Vinyls")

def homeMenu():

    x = 0
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input('''
SELECT AN OPTION
1) Add record
2) Delete record
3) View Genre
4) View Artist
5) View Size
6) View Favorites
7) Edit
8) QUIT
'''))
       except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid option")
            continue
        if x >=1 and x <=8:
            return x
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid option")




def addRecord(musicDict):
    print("add") # Not for final product
    x = input("Please enter the Artist name: ")
    y = input("Please enter the Album name: " )
    tempDict = {x : y}
    musicDict = musicDict| tempDict
    return musicDict

def removeRecord(musicDict):
    print("remove") # Not for final product
    print(musicDict)
    x = input("Please enter the Artist name you want to remove: ")
    del musicDict[x]
    return musicDict

def viewGenre(musicDict):
    print("genre") # Not for final product
    print(musicDict)
    return musicDict

def viewArtist(musicDict):
    print("artist")
    print(musicDict)
    return musicDict

def viewSize(musicDict):
    print("size") # Not for final product
    print(musicDict)
    return musicDict

def viewFavorites(musicDict):
    print("favorites") # Not for final product
    print(musicDict)
    return musicDict

def editRec(musicDict):
    print("edit") # Not for final product
    print(musicDict)
    return musicDict

def quitApp():
    exit()



def main():
    musicDict = {}
    welcome()
    x = 0
    while x != 8:
        x = homeMenu()
        if x == 1:
            musicDict = addRecord(musicDict)
        elif x == 2:
            musicDict = removeRecord(musicDict)
        elif x == 3:
            musicDict = viewGenre(musicDict)
        elif x == 4:
            musicDict = viewArtist(musicDict)
        elif x == 5:
            musicDict = viewSize(musicDict)
        elif x == 6:
            musicDict = viewFavorites(musicDict)
        elif x == 7:
            musicDict = editRec(musicDict)
        else:
            quit





main()
```

Comment: A dictionary might not be the best choice of container. If really you want to develop a useful application, consider using a small database (SQLite?). You'll have to learn the syntax but this will make your life easier for filtering the data any way you want.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/sort-dictionary-by-value-in-python/ try sorted